# Magento - change address to which confirmation is sent after newsletter subscription

Tags: magento

By default, Magento sends out a confirmation email (to the user) after a user subscribes to the newsletter. Is it possible to change the email address to which the confirmation is sent?

Thanks

Comment: The email address is the user's. Where else are you looking to send it?

Comment: To the store admin. It will be more of "notify the admin" than a "confirmation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to my answer to your question about changing the action path of the `subscribe.phtml` file.  If you override the `newAction` in `subscriberController.php`, you will be able to add in all your extra requirements, such as emailing the store admin, changing the information in the outgoing email, etc.

There is a detailed [walkthrough](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller) on the Magento wiki on how to configure Magento to use your custom controller instead of the core.  This is best practice as it means that future patches/upgrades from Magento shouldn't break your customization.